# Validating XML file with XML::Schematron::LibXSLT

Tags: perl, xslt, xml-validation, schematron

I want to verify XML file using XML::Schematron::LibXSLT
here is code i tried which uses .sch schemafile and XML file as argument

```
use XML::Schematron::LibXSLT;

my $schema_file = $ARGV[0];
my $xml_file    = $ARGV[1];

die "Usage: perl schematron.pl schemafile XMLfile.\n"
    unless defined $schema_file and defined $xml_file;

my $tron = XML::Schematron::LibXSLT->new();

$tron->schema($schema_file);
my $ret = $tron->verify($xml_file);

print $ret . "\n";
```

It is giving error `Can't locate object method "new" via package "XML::Schematron::LibXSLT" at schematron.pl line 14.` which tell module don't have new method. May be module is updated.

So I also tried

```
use XML::Schematron;

my $pseudotron = XML::Schematron->new_with_traits( traits => ['LibXSLT'], schema => "$schema_file");
my $messages = $pseudotron->verify($xml_file);

print "$messages\n";
```

But it dosen't print anything. Don't know what is wrong!

Also at https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Schematron::LibXSLT **Synopsis**, 2nd and 3rd use are giving same error.

Please refer to the [perlmonk](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1095291) link as well for the same post

Comment: The documentation shows `use XML::Schematron`, not `use XML::Schematron::LibXSLT`.

Comment: @chobara I also tried it. `use XML::Schematron::LibXSLT` is used in many online tutorials which i tried in first attempt, where I got above error. Please check my second attempt.